# Unprotect a particular <Location> when the entire site is protected with mod-auth-openidc

Tags: mod-auth-openidc

I have an apache 2.4 site protect with mod-auth-openidc.  Is there a way to unprotect a particular  within that protected area?  Right now my apache config has one small  paragraph where mod-auth-openidc is configured to protect the entire site.  I discovered there are three  out of a possible 137 that don't need to be protected.  If there is no way to unprotect a  then I will have to individually protect or unprotect all 137 .  That's a lot of configuration changes.

In the past I've been able to unprotect specific locations by creating a  tag and specifying Allow from all and Satisfy any.  This doesn't work when using mod-auth-openidc.  I also found a post that talked about providing public access by using SetEnvIf but that doesn't work either.

```
<Location /mynewsite>
   # Protect everything using oidc
   AuthType openid-connect
   Require claim "sub~^employeeGroup2*"
   # Don't protect employeeplans
   SetEnvIf Request_URI "(/mynewsite/employeeplans/)$" allow  
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from env=allow
   Satisfy any         
</Location>
```

I'm not going to create 137  config paragraphs in my apache config.  If there is no solution I'll have to scrap this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `AuthType None` on those paths should do it.